# white background before slider loads

Tags: bootstrap-4, slider, drupal-9, slider-revolution

I have an issue tried to figure out but faild. I have website link https://tilesw.asycuda.org/  made in bootstrap while the page laods first a white screen comes. I dont know cause that. If someone can kindly tell me how to fix it.[website on-reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ac0A.png)[enter link description here](https://tilesw.asycuda.org/)

Answer (score 0):

plz check your HTML code which I marked in the image, i mean it's not load HTML

[image]